# Get number of specific element in each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, like the following:

```
True True
False True
```

I would like to count the number of `True` values for each row, something like

```
df.count(value=True, axis=1)
```

or

```
df.apply(count(False), axis=1)
```

It should return `2 1`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df.sum(axis=1)
```

This relies on the fact that `True` is counted as 1 and `False` as 0, and is optimally efficient.

Comment: Thanks. For other readers looking for a general solution: to count the number of e.g. sevens (7) in each row, you'd do (df == 7).sum(axis=1).